# Como recebo o dado 'distancia' em JSON nesse exemplo?

Tags: php, json, api, google-maps

Como recebo o dado 'distancia' em JSON nesse exemplo?

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=86015-810&destinations=86830-000&key=AIzaSyDL6_dJ-Mbi_03_g6lHhWibxY22Z2UeYZQ";

$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);

echo $json_data["text"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse echo já deve resolver seu problema

```
$json_data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']
```

Comment: Valeu mesmo!! Funcionou :D